# Manipulator Icons Missing in the 3D Viewport (2.8)

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, 3d-manipulator

I'm not sure if I toggled something and it made my manipulator icons disappear, but I can't find them when I would select an object or face, edge, or vertex. Help?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "Overlays" box (Either at the top or bottom of the viewport), make sure to scroll and find the Gizmos section. When found, make sure the "Active Tools" is highlighted.